# How do I use formidable.js with passport authenticate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Last time I used passport authenticate for login in the following manner:

```
router.post('/login', parserUrlEncodedTrue, (request, res, next) => {
  console.log('logging in user');

  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    var options = "";
    if(err){ 
      return next(err);
    }

    if(!user){
      return res.json({ 
        error: true, 
        message: "User doesn't exist" 
      });
    }

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err){
        return next(err); 
      }

      return res.json({
        error: false,
        message: "Login Success"
      });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
```

Now I'm trying to use formidable.js and it works fine for registration but can't make it work with login.

```
let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();  
 form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if(err){
      helpers.errors(err, res);
    } else { 
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {})(req, res, next);
}
});
```

passport.authenticate gets to req before it is parsed by formidable. I'm also using express and passport-local-mongoose.